# How can plot absolute inequality in complex number

Tags: plotting, complex

I am new to Mathematica and i would like to know how to plot a complex function..

[image]

I cant plot absolute inequality...

Comment: You could use the previous answers you got some time ago!  Try  `RegionPlot[
 Abs[(2 - u)^2 - I v ]^2 < Abs[u + I v ]^2 , {u, -1, 4}, {v, -5, 5}]`

Comment: thank you thank you,,,,ㅠㅠㅠ

Comment: You're welcome!